# Application of transformers to tabular data

Tags: transformer, transfer-learning

Is anyone using transformer based models for tabular data in real data science jobs as of 2024

I mean models like

- Tabnet
- Tabtransformer
- ARM-net
- SAINT
- FT-Transformer
- Non-Parametric Transformers

I got these models from a blog post https://levelup.gitconnected.com/tabula-rasa-could-we-have-a-transformer-for-tabular-data-9e4b238cde2c and it also lists the paper "Why do tree-based models still outperform deep learning on tabular data?" Which claims tree-base models would still be superior.

I wonder if this still holds true in 2024. Maybe also somebody found a suitable transfer learning task where he profited from the deep learning methods a lot.